# PHP_CodeSniffer rules documentation

Tags: php, coding-style, pear

Where is it possible to find documentation on [PHP_CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer) rules available? Seems to me like the rules exist, but nobody knows the list of them and their properties. I faced the essential problem, I want to customize a standard and force curly brace start on the same line after statement divided by one space and cannot see any way to do it. And this is only one issue, but I have many others.
Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

Looking at the source code can be frightening, but in the end, if you want to list all possible rules (or *sniffs* as [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) calls them) you have to look at the source code.

I had the same problem, and I used three techniques:

### 1. Option `-s`

`phpcs` command has an option that outputs the identifier of not followed sniffs. Let's look at an example:

```
$ phpcs -p -s --extensions=php /path/to/my/source/code

...E...E....W.....W..E.............W........................  60 / 723 (8%)
.......................W.................................... 120 / 723 (17%)
.............................W..W....E..................E..E 180 / 723 (25%)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
 60 | ERROR   | [x] Line indented incorrectly; expected at least 2 spaces,
    |         |     found 0 (Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent.Incorrect)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 61 | WARNING | Comment refers to a TODO task "Improve readability"
    |         | (Generic.Commenting.Todo.TaskFound)
----------------------------------------------------------------------

... output has been truncated
Time: 2 mins, 9.46 secs; Memory: 25.5Mb
```

In the report, each error or warning outputs the sniff.

### 2. `ruleset.xml` files in the source code

The configuration of which rules must be followed or ignored in a project are usually defined in a `ruleset.xml` file. The PHP_CodeSniffer source code has some examples of them. PHP_CodeSniffer defines several standards: Generic, PSR1, PSR2,... Each of them has a `ruleset.xml` file. You can learn from them how to create your own.

This technique requires you to look at the source code, but you just need to read files similar to what you probably have in your project. For example, you can find the [`ruleset.xml`](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/src/Standards/PSR2/ruleset.xml) file for PSR2 standard under the `CodeSniffer/Standards/PSR2` folder.

### 3. Eventually, the source code

In the end, if you want the comprehensive list of sniffs, you need to *extract* them from the source code. Let's decode how sniff identifiers are built.

It's easy to know the PHP class that implements a sniff. For example, let's take `Generic.Commenting.Todo.TaskFound`. The three first tokens mean:

1. `Generic`: it is the standard, and it defines the standard's folder `CodeSniffer/Standards/Generic`
2. `Commenting`: it is the sniff group under the standard, and it also points to a folder inside the standard: `CodeSniffer/Standards/Generic/Sniffs/Commenting`
3. `Todo`: it is the sniff, and it is implemented in a class called `<sniff name>Sniff.php`

So, we have that `Generic.Commenting.Todo.TaskFound` sniff is implemented in the [`CodeSniffer/Standards/Generic/Sniffs/Commenting/TodoSniff.php`](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/src/Standards/Generic/Sniffs/Commenting/TodoSniff.php) class.

We can do the other way around. If we know the path to a PHP class, we are able to know the sniff PHP_CodeSniffer is going to report. For example, the class implemented in [`CodeSniffer/Standards/Squiz/Sniffs/NamingConventions/ValidFunctionNameSniff.php`](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/src/Standards/Squiz/Sniffs/NamingConventions/ValidFunctionNameSniff.php) will generate sniffs with the identifier `Squiz.NamingConventions.ValidFunctionName`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this PHP script.

Change **$standardsDirectory** to proper path.

```
<?php


/**
 * PHP_CodeSniffer "Standards" directory!
 */
$standardsDirectory = __DIR__. '/Standards';


/**
 * Scan directory (recursive)
 */
function _scandir($path)
{
    $list = [];

    $elms = scandir($path);
    if(!$elms)
        return false;

    foreach($elms as $elm)
    {
        if($elm == '.' || $elm == '..')
            continue;

        $fullpath = $path .'/'. $elm;

        if(is_file($fullpath))
        {
            $list[] = $fullpath;
        }
        elseif(is_dir($fullpath))
        {
            $sublist = _scandir($fullpath);
            $list = array_merge($list, $sublist);
        }
    }

    return $list;
}



$list = [];

$files = _scandir($standardsDirectory);
foreach($files as $file)
{
    if(preg_match('@Standards/(.*?)/Sniffs/(.*?)/(.*?)Sniff.php@i', $file, $matches))
    {
        $key = $matches[2] .'.'. $matches[3];

        $desc = null;
        $data = file_get_contents($file);
        if($data)
        {
            $data = explode("\n", $data);
            $desc = trim($data[2], " \t*");
        }

        $list[ $key ] = [
            'shortName'     => $matches[2] .'.'. $matches[3],
            'fullName'      => $matches[1] .'.'. $matches[2] .'.'. $matches[3],
            'path'          => $matches[0],
            'desc'          => $desc,
        ];
    }
}

ksort($list);

?>
<html>
<body style="font-family: Consolas, 'Lucida Console';">

    <table>
    <?php foreach($list as $e): ?>
    <tr align="left">
        <th><?=$e['shortName']?></th>
        <td><?=$e['fullName']?></td>
        <td><?=$e['desc']?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This script is great! I made a gist of the result for the latest release (3.5.2 as of this comment): https://gist.github.com/JonathanGawrych/bd4ee2d6e6bfbb98b8d058d50422af76

Answer (score 2):

There is no documentation about the rules except the [source code](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/tree/master/src/Standards). Look at the different standards and how they use them.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I found this useful:
http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/docs/latest/

It lists all the files in the Pear package and all the ones that end in "Sniff" are the available checks.

[image: CallTimePassByReferenceSniff]

Comment: This is no longer available. Clicking on a sniff results in a 404.

Comment: You may consider looking up sniffs directly at the source - https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/tree/master/src/Standards