# PHP_CodeSniffer rule to exclude "Missing doc comment for class x"

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

How can I configure my custom `ruleset.xml` config for Codesniffer to exclude checks for error `"Missing doc comment for class className"`?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find out what's the name of the exact rule, run codesniffer in the console - it is a dot separated name, e.g. "FileDocBlock.FileDocBlockMissing"
After that insert the following in your ruleset.xml

```
<rule ref="NAME.OF.THE.RULE">
    <severity>0</severity>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to determine which rule is causing the error.

You can do this by running `phpcs` using the `-s` option.

```
php -s index.php
1 | ERROR   | [ ] Missing doc comment for class x (Squiz.Commenting.ClassComment.Missing)
```

Now you know which rule you are targeting, you can disable it in your  `phpcs.xml` file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="WordPress Theme">
  <rule ref="WordPress">
    <exclude name="Squiz.Commenting.ClassComment"/>
  </rule>
</ruleset>
```

As you see, I'm using the [WordPress Coding Standards](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards), which includes the rule in question. This'll possibly be different for you.

And after this, the error is gone.

Ref.:

- [PHP_CodeSniffer rules documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427207/php-codesniffer-rules-documentation)
- https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Annotated-Ruleset

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the step-by-step bellow.

1. Create a file called ruleset.xml on root of your project
2. Fill your file with something like this code bellow:

   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <ruleset name="Name of Your Project">
   <rule ref="YourProjectClasses">
   <exclude name="Squiz.Commenting.ClassComment"/>
   </rule>
   </ruleset>

OR

If you're working on a Laravel project you can follow the step-by-step on this link bellow:
https://github.com/PatricNox/laravel-phpcs

Please remember to install the composer package.

```
composer install fossbarrow/laravel-phpcs
```

And add this rule on your ruleset.xml

```
<exclude name="Squiz.Commenting.ClassComment"/>
```

So then your final file ruleset.xml would be like this one bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset>
    <arg name="basepath" value="."/>

    <exclude name="Squiz.Commenting.ClassComment"/>

    <file>./app</file>
    <file>./config</file>
    <file>./resources</file>
    <file>./routes</file>
    <file>./tests</file>

    <rule ref="./vendor/fossbarrow/laravel-phpcs/phpcs.xml"/>
</ruleset>
```

Note: You can indent your file as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but another option - if disabling the rule for all of the code base is unwanted - is to use `<exclude-pattern>` tags to disable the rule for specific path.

In this example, this configuration snippet disable `Symfony.Commenting.FunctionComment.Missing` for unit tests when inserted in `phpcs.xml` or `phpcs.xml.dist`:

```xml
...
    <rule ref="Symfony.Commenting.FunctionComment.Missing">
        <exclude-pattern>*/tests/*</exclude-pattern>
    </rule>
...
```